# Integrating Karma JavaScript testing with Maven

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, maven, karma-runner

I'm adding Karma-based JS unit tests to Maven. I used the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <browsers>Chrome</browsers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Tests work separately (without Maven) on my machine when I use `karma start karma.conf.js`, but with Maven I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.kelveden:maven-karma-plugin:1.0:start (default) 
on project web: There was an error executing Karma. Cannot run program "karma":
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal
com.kelveden:maven-karma-plugin:1.0:start (default) on project web: 
There was an error executing Karma.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "karma": CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at com.kelveden.karma.StartMojo.createKarmaProcess(StartMojo.java:151)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 23 more
```

Here is why I find it a bit strange: according to [this class](https://github.com/karma-runner/maven-karma-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kelveden/karma/StartMojo.java), the `karma.conf.js` should be found by default (`@Parameter(defaultValue = "${basedir}/karma.conf.js", property = "configFile", required = true)`). Also, I tried to pass the path, absolute and relative, in the `-DconfigFile=...` parameter, it didn't work. I used Windows, but I think it shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure what exactly can be wrong in the configuration, an advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was a bug, that's already fixed.

I tried to run tests again with version `1.2-SNAPSHOT` of this plugin (cloned it and built) and it started the Karma properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that karma.conf.js is in place (i.e. the parameter does work) but rather 'karma' executable is not, according to

`final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("karma", "start", configFile.getAbsolutePath());`

from the file you've mentioned.